# MySQL comparing counts from same column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, phpmyadmin

I have the following table structures:-

```
Brand 

id   |  bname  | desc 
----------------------


Products 

pid   |  bid_fk  |  name  |  rating  |  type 
---------------------------------------------
```

Given that a product `type` may be 'S' or 'T', I want to `SELECT` the brands which have more products of type 'S' than type 'T'

I have tried using `COUNT` but I do not know how to compare the `COUNT` of the two types in the Products table.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`statement and compare count of `S` with count of `T`.
To get counts you can use `CASE` statement like this:

```
SELECT b.id,MAX(b.bname)
FROM Brand b
JOIN Product p on (p.bid_fk=b.id)
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN p.type='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.type='T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```